# IF Statement Incorrectly Evaluating to True when Using Optional Values in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa

I have set up my view controllers so that they send a notification once their `-viewDidLoad` method is about to return. For example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Do Stuff
        var notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter();
        notificationCenter.postNotificationName("AViewControllerDidLoadNotification", object: self);
    }
}
```

My `AppDelegate` class is listening for this notification and implementing the method shown in this picture.[image]

In case the picture isn't loading, the method takes the notification sent by the view controllers as it's only argument and then tests whether the `UIViewController`'s `title` property has a non-nil value. If the title property is non-nil it logs the title.

However, as you can see in the debugger panel, the `title` property of the view controller is `nil` and the `if` statement is still evaluating to `true`.

I am admittedly new to optional values. But I have recreated this situation in a swift playground and the `if` statement evaluates to false. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you keep going? You are paused on the `var controller` line. If you keep stepping, what is logged?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift. What type is notification.object.title? Have you confirmed you're not comparing objects of different types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've gotten yourself into rather an odd situation with your very peculiar use of the expression `notification.object?.title`, because `notification.object` is not, of itself, a UIViewController. It is an AnyObject.

Now, an AnyObject has no known properties, so it has no `title` and your expression, it would seem, should not even compile. But, by a special dispensation coming from certain oddities of Objective-C, you are in fact allowed to ask about an AnyObject's properties anyway. But when you do, the result is itself an Optional, because no such property might exist.

Thus, you are actually testing, not the value of a view controller's `title` property, but whether this unknown object *has* a `title` property in the first place; and if in fact it *does* have a `title` property at all, the value of that `title` property is *double-wrapped* inside that Optional.

To see this clearly, just test this (silly) code:

```
let n = NSNotification(name: "Howdy", object: "Hi")
let t = n.object?.title
```

Look at *what type `t` is*. It is not a `String?`; it is a `String??`. That's your double-wrapped Optional. This means that it *would* be an Optional-wrapping-a-String in case this object turns out to have a `title` property, but just in case, that value has itself been wrapped in an Optional.

Thus, your test doesn't do what you want it to do. To do what you want to do, just speak much more plainly and simply. You need to cast the `object` to a UIViewController *first*, and *then* examine its `title`. Like this:

```
func aViewControllerDidLoad(notification:NSNotification) {
    if let vc = notification.object as? UIViewController {
        if vc.title != nil {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```